# Vue vee-validate validate input forms with router-link button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vee-validate

I'm using *vee-validate* on a form with plenty of inputs, therefore I have 3 form pages, using `<router-link/>` buttons to navigate between each other. I would like to know if there is a way to use `<router-link/>` with vee-validate in order to validate the inputs each time I'm clicking on the `<router-link/>` to access to the next form page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can check if all validation rules have been met. Use the following code.

```
this.$validator.validateAll().then(isValidationSuccess => {
    if (isValidationSuccess) {
        // Do something on validation success
    } else {
        // Validation failed
    }
})
```